# Disable csrf validation for some requests on Express

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I'm writing a small web app with Node.js using the Express framework. I'm using the csrf middleware, but I want to disable it for some requests. This is how I include it in my app:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret: 'secret'}));
app.use(express.csrf());
```

I want to set a POST route without the csrf control.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are several possible approaches. You basically need to understand what is the simplest and most correct rule to decide whether or not to use the csrf middleware. If you want csrf most of the time, except for a small whitelist of request patterns, follow the example in [this answer I have about conditional logging middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9351428/266795) (copied below for convenience).

```
var express = require("express");
var csrf = express.csrf();
var app = express.createServer();

var conditionalCSRF = function (req, res, next) {
  //compute needCSRF here as appropriate based on req.path or whatever
  if (needCSRF) {
    csrf(req, res, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

app.use(conditionalCSRF);
app.listen(3456);
```

Another approaches could be only using the middleware on a certain path like `app.post('/forms/*', express.csrf())`. You just want to find an expressive way to make it clean when the middleware will or will not be used.

Comment: please note that if you use csurf and not express.csrf, this won't work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992139/node-js-use-csurf-conditionally-with-express-4

Comment: See the following issue that says it doesn't work..Has any thing changed in recent versions that makes it not to work?? https://github.com/expressjs/csurf/issues/23

Comment: Wonderful!  Saved my butt.

Comment: could anyone please tell me how you peoples compute needCSRf

Comment: The question asker said they wanted to disable CSRF for "some requests" without specifying which requests or criteria, so my answer presumes they have some application-specific criteria for which requests do or do not need CSRF. If you have a standard application, using CSRF always is probably correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since Express middleware executes in order,  you could always put your statements above the csrf() statement in the code.

Like this:

```
app.get '/ping', (req, res) -> res.status(200).end()
app.use csrf()
```

Express will return before your csrf token gets set.  For very small numbers of endpoints (I just have one that fits this category), I've found this to be a cleaner solution.

Also, as of this writing, the code for the above answer would look like this:

```
customCsrf = (req, res, next) ->
  if req?.url isnt '/ping'
    return csrf()(req, res, next)
  else
    return next()

app.use customCsrf
```

That extra (req, res, next) tripped me up for awhile, so hope this helps someone.

Comment: I think it would have been helpful to respond to the user in the same syntax as they wrote the question in.

Answer (score 1):

[dailyjs.com](http://dailyjs.com/2012/09/13/express-3-csrf-tutorial/) has a good article about csrf and express. It basically works like this:

use the csrf middleware:

```
app.configure(function() {
  // ...
  app.use(express.csrf());
  // ..
});
```

create a custom middleware that sets the local variable `token` to the csrf value:

```
function csrf(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
  next();
}
```

use your custom middleware in every route you want:

```
app.get('/', csrf, function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

in your form create a hidden field that holds the csrf value:

```
form(action='/contact', method='post')
  input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=token)
```

Comment: where do you actually validate the token?

Comment: validation is done by the csrf middleware on `POST` requests. see the [docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html)

Comment: i don't see anything. I would expect if ( token == req.session._csrf ) somewhere.

Comment: That doesn't do selective csrf on a per route basis. It only provides a convenience to add the token where needed. Omitting the 'csrf' middleware will throw a 403

Answer (score 1):

Use the middleware at express app level adding every HTTP method to the ignored list, to ensure that the protection **does not** verify by default.

E.g.

```
const ignoredMethods = [
    'GET',
    'HEAD',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
    'DELETE',
    'OPTIONS'
]

const csrfInit = csurf({ignoredMethods, cookie: true });
app.use(csrfInit);
```

This will inject the csrfToken() method into each request object allowing the setup of a hidden field or consumable cookie by the application.

Then add a protected version in your as middleware to desired routes, and ignore the ones that do not require it.

E.g. Protected

```
const csrfProtection = csurf({ cookie: true });


router.post('/api/foo', csrfProtection, (req, res, next) => ...
```

E.g. Unprotected

```
const csrfProtection = csurf({ cookie: true });


router.post('/api/foo', (req, res, next) => ...
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
const csrf = require("csurf");
const ROOT_IGNORE_LIST = ["/api/authenticate"];
const csrfMiddleware = csrf({
      cookie: true,
      ignoreMethods: ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"],
});

// Create middleware to check request url
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  if (ROOT_IGNORE_LIST.includes(req.url)) {
    next();
  } else {
    csrfMiddleware(req, res, next);
  }
}).use("/api", routes);
```