# CSRF with Twilio

Tags: express, csrf, twilio

I am trying to get Twilio to work with my express/node.js installation.  Twilio is making an incoming connection to my server, when it gets a text message.  Then I am replying to this with a SMS response.

This works the first time.  Then the second time, my server blocks Twilio because it says that it was a forged request.

Is there a proper way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should disable CSRF for that URL. See this question on how to do that: [Disable csrf validation for some requests on Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516898/disable-csrf-validation-for-some-requests-on-express)

CSRF is a vulnerability that only pertains to requests that require session information in the form of a cookie (which is why CSRF is also sometimes called "session riding"). In short, CSRF is when a malicious site owner can use a `<form>` tag on a page they control to post a form to your site, causing an authenticated request to be sent to your server without the user's knowing. For instance, let's say Facebook has a /delete_user.php which deletes the current authenticated user. A CSRF attack on that URL will be in the form (no pun intended) of a `<form action="http://facebook.com/delete_user.php">` tag on the malicious site owner's site, which gets submitted without the user's knowledge. A non-CSRF-safe implementation of /delete_user.php will see the user's auth cookie and delete the user -- much to the user's dismay.

Anyway, long story short, your Twilio handler does not require a user's browser cookie, and thus is not subject to CSRF attacks. Just disable CSRF checks for the Twilio callback URLs.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful explanation.  I I will disable the csrf check for that controller.  I am curious though, why the browser would allow another webpage to ride on top of another's requests.  Why doesn't the browser partition the cookies between site?

Comment: The browser *does* partition cookies between sites. At no point in time does the attacker have access to the actual facebook.com cookies (to continue my example from above). This attack is performed to submit a GET/POST request to cause some side effect, inside of the user's browser.