# sails.js enable csrf for browser access and disable csrf for native app access

Tags: node.js, mobile, sails.js, csrf

I'm using sails.js as backend, or, more generally, nodejs.

The admin page of my website is accessed by browser, and yet for all the non-admin users, they should access my backend resource through native mobile app(iOS/Android).

I figured that for native app restful http requests, it is not necessary to enable csrf protection, yet for admin page browser access, it is.

So I wonder if it's possible to enable csrf protection for browser access and disable csrf protection for mobile native app access?

Answer (score 3):

You can use different controller/ route to be partially load which endpoint that use CSRF. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847967/can-certain-urls-be-exempt-from-csrf-in-sails-js).

Comment: Yup, I made it done by differentiating all the mobile http requests by adding '/mobile/*' in the front of the url, and then add all the mobile request urls in config/csrf.js like so:

routesDisabled: '/mobile/submit_login,/mobile/upload_user_avatar'

Although it's weird that routesDisabled doesn't support the wildcard way, i.e. 

routesDisabled: '/mobile/*'

Comment: Thanks @dulan for sharing your solution, I am also looking for doing this.